# Node - Stub class constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, sinon

I've been looking for a solution for quite some time without luck, I have the following code I'd like to test:

**some_script.js**

```
var Model = require('./models')

exports.tokenizeCard = function (args) {
    var model = new Model('SOME_NAME', args);

    return utils.postXMLRequest('SOME_URL'), model.xml);
}
```

**models.js**

```
class models {
    constructor(model, args, order) {
        this.xml = '<fake>some_text</fake>'
    }
}
```

I would like to stub that constructor so I can return a custom test object, or failing that, the whole class. I know I can have some function that returns a new instance nad stub that function, like so:

```
exports.tokenizeCard = function (args) {
    var model = getModel(args);
    ...
}

function getModel(args){
    return new Model(args))
}
```

But I would really like to avoid that and stub directly if possible, if anyone has a solution it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you try something like `sinon.stub(Model.prototype, 'xml').returns('something')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, I use one of the following libs to do it:

- https://github.com/jhnns/rewire
- https://github.com/speedskater/babel-plugin-rewire (when import is used)
- https://github.com/mfncooper/mockery
- https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire (you can also take a look at this one but I haven't provided a sample for it)

There are 3 different samples below:

```js
// using rewire
const rewire = require('rewire');
const lib = rewire('some_script.js')

describe('some script', () => {
  it('tokenizeCard', () => {
    const modelStub = sinon.stub();
    const revert = lib.__set__('Model', modelStub);

    lib.tokenizeCard('foo', 'bar');

    modelStub.calledWithNew();
    modelStub.calledWith('SOME_NAME', 'foo', 'bar');

    revert();
  });
});
```

```js
// using babel-plugin-rewire
import lib, {__RewireAPI__} from 'some_script.js'

describe('some script', () => {
  it('tokenizeCard', () => {
    const modelStub = sinon.stub();
    __RewireAPI__.__Rewire__('Model', modelStub);

    lib.tokenizeCard('foo', 'bar');

    modelStub.calledWithNew();
    modelStub.calledWith('SOME_NAME', 'foo', 'bar');

    __RewireAPI__.__ResetDependency__('Model');
  });
});
```

```js
// using mockery
// 
// NOTE:
// This one will work only if you have dynamic require
// Let's say you have
// var Model = require('./models')
// inside tokenizeCard
const mockery = require('mockery');
const lib = require('some_script.js')

describe('some script', () => {
  before(() => {
    mockery.enable();
  });
  
  after(() => {
    mockery.disable();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    mockery.deregisterAll();
  });

  it('tokenizeCard', () => {
    const modelStub = sinon.stub();
    mockery.registerMock('./models', modelStub);

    lib.tokenizeCard('foo', 'bar');

    modelStub.calledWithNew();
    modelStub.calledWith('SOME_NAME', 'foo', 'bar');
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I was using the 1st posted option with rewire, but didn't know if there was some native way to do it with Sinon, guess not.

Answer (score 0):

A 3rd option that would remove the need for hacky import patches would be to [have the caller inject it](http://var%20Model%20=%20require('./models')%20%20exports.tokenizeCard%20=%20function%20(args)%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20var%20model%20=%20new%20Model('SOME_NAME',%20args);%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20utils.postXMLRequest('SOME_URL'),%20model.xml);%20%7D), so that `tokenizeCard` is no longer directly dependent on `Model`.

This will allow the caller to provide a model, so the production code can use `Model` and your test code can trivially create a stub and call `tokenizeCard` with it.

```
var Model = require('./models')

exports.tokenizeCard = function (args, M) {
    M = M || Model;
    var model = new M('SOME_NAME', args);

    return utils.postXMLRequest('SOME_URL'), model.xml);
}
```

The above is an intermediary refactor that sort of half breaks the dependency.  Not specifying `M` will default to the `Model`, but providing `M` as a stub in your test allows you to configure a stub object and verify that `tokenizeCard` works in an easier, and more maintainable, way than stubbing/patching `Model`.